# Python Linear Programming Binary exclusive or choose only one group

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to identify the designers with best cost to finish the complete dress.

The Conditions:

1. Need to get complete dress
2. Either Paul1 or Paul2 can be selected but not both even though the
   combination of these two could be the best cost.

| Dress | John | Chris | Paul1 | Paul2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shirt | 6.33 | 6.62 | 6.37 | 6.52 |
| Trouser | 6.76 | 6.62 | 6.37 | 6.76 |
| Jacket | 6.84 | 6.62 | 6.34 | 6.20 |

Here is the result of the model from Python and Pulp:

MINIMIZE

6.84 * x_0 + 6.62 * x_1 + 6.37 * x_10 + 6.76 * x_11 + 6.34 * x_2 + 6.2 * x_3 + 6.33 * x_4 + 6.62 * x_5 + 6.37 * x_6 + 6.76 * x_7 + 6.76 * x_8 + 6.62 * x_9 + 0.0

SUBJECT TO

C1: x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1

C2: x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 1

C3: x_10 + x_11 + x_8 + x_9 = 1

I couldn't figure it out the condition to choose either Paul1 or Paul2 but not both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is continuous to the question: [Linear Programming Binary Variable Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878308/linear-programming-binary-variable-grouping)

Comment: Please show the code for your current invocation of pulp.

Comment: It sounds like the constraint you need is a simple sum of the assignment variables for Paul1 and Paul2.

Comment: You already have the structure of the problem, a good understanding of the math model, and a working toy example in Excel.  I think it would be helpful for you to read the `pulp` dox, some examples, and try to piece this together and learn the syntax a bit.  If you get stuck, edit this post and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: When you describe exclusive selection between Paul1 and Paul2, do you mean per dress item? Or do you mean that if _any_ dress item is bought from one of the Pauls, no dress item can be bough from the other Paul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way to choose either paul1 or paul2 isn't introduce 2 binary variable indexed over `y[p1]` & `y[p2]`. Then following constraints
`y[p1]<= sum(x[p1,c] over c)<=3y[p1]` 
`y[p2]<= sum(x[p2,c] over c)<=3y[p2]` 
`y[p1] + y[p2]<= 1`
where `c` represents `{shirt, trouser, jacket}`.

The above constraints choose either `p1` or `p2` for all or none of the clothing items.

Answer (score 1):

You need better variable and constraint names, and you have only one constraint (the exclusive vendor selection per row):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp


def make_assignment(suffix: str) -> pulp.LpVariable:
    return pulp.LpVariable(name='asn_' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpBinary)


def constrain_rows(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    names = (row.name + '_' + row.index).to_series(index=row.index)
    vars = names.apply(make_assignment)
    prob.addConstraint(name='excl_' + row.name, constraint=1 == pulp.lpSum(vars))
    return vars


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'John':  (6.33, 6.76, 6.84),
    'Chris': (6.62, 6.62, 6.62),
    'Paul1': (6.37, 6.37, 6.34),
    'Paul2': (6.52, 6.76, 6.20),
}, index=pd.Index(name='Dress', data=('Shirt', 'Trouser', 'Jacket')))

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='dress_vendors', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
assigns = df.apply(func=constrain_rows, axis=1)
prob.objective = pulp.lpDot(assigns.values.ravel(), df.values.ravel())
print(prob)
prob.solve()

_, used = assigns.applymap(pulp.LpVariable.value).values.nonzero()
for dress, vendor in zip(df.index, df.columns[used]):
    print(f'{dress} bought from {vendor}')
print(f'Dress total is ${prob.objective.value():.2f}')
```

```
dress_vendors:
MINIMIZE
6.62*asn_Jacket_Chris + 6.84*asn_Jacket_John + 6.34*asn_Jacket_Paul1 + 6.2*asn_Jacket_Paul2 + 6.62*asn_Shirt_Chris + 6.33*asn_Shirt_John + 6.37*asn_Shirt_Paul1 + 6.52*asn_Shirt_Paul2 + 6.62*asn_Trouser_Chris + 6.76*asn_Trouser_John + 6.37*asn_Trouser_Paul1 + 6.76*asn_Trouser_Paul2 + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
excl_Shirt: asn_Shirt_Chris + asn_Shirt_John + asn_Shirt_Paul1
 + asn_Shirt_Paul2 = 1

excl_Trouser: asn_Trouser_Chris + asn_Trouser_John + asn_Trouser_Paul1
 + asn_Trouser_Paul2 = 1

excl_Jacket: asn_Jacket_Chris + asn_Jacket_John + asn_Jacket_Paul1
 + asn_Jacket_Paul2 = 1

VARIABLES
0 <= asn_Jacket_Chris <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Jacket_John <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Jacket_Paul1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Jacket_Paul2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Shirt_Chris <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Shirt_John <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Shirt_Paul1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Shirt_Paul2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Trouser_Chris <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Trouser_John <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Trouser_Paul1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_Trouser_Paul2 <= 1 Integer

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc /tmp/1eacd290c9f44c86a43b0722be3104de-pulp.mps timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /tmp/1eacd290c9f44c86a43b0722be3104de-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 8 COLUMNS
At line 57 RHS
At line 61 BOUNDS
At line 74 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 3 rows, 12 columns and 12 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 18.9 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 0 rows, 0 columns (0 integer (0 of which binary)) and 0 elements
Cbc3007W No integer variables - nothing to do
Cuts at root node changed objective from 18.9 to -1.79769e+308
Probing was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                18.90000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Shirt bought from John
Trouser bought from Paul1
Jacket bought from Paul2
Dress total is $18.90
```